# Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(cmd, params, method, ...) :

Tags: r, twitter, oauth

I am requesting userTimeLine multiple times trough a function and taking output as time, URL, location etc.

the connection is established once but still sometime during the function execution it is throwing the below error. I am not able to understand the cause of the error.

---

Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(cmd, params, method, ...) : 
  OAuth authentication error:
This most likely means that you have incorrectly called setup_twitter_oauth()'

---